# Function name conflict. How to call a MATLAB toolbox function instead an user-defined function

Tags: matlab

I have a problem that I could solve by changing my function's name. But I want to know if there's an option to call a MATLAB-defined function which has the same name of my user-defined function. By default, MATLAB always uses the user-defined function, but I want to use both in the same script.
Any idea?

MATLABfuzzytoolbox::addrule();
userDefined::addrule()

Comment: Matlab will use whichever script shows up first in the search path. If you always want to use Matlab's, either change the name or call it using the full path to the .m file

Answer (score 7):

Matlab uses the first function with the specified name that shows up in the path, and there is no mechanism to call specifically one of the functions sharing the same name.

A good practice is to put your functions into [packages](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/scoping-classes-with-packages.html). In this way you can name them with the same name than a built-in function, but the call is slightly different: for instance if you have a function `addrule` in the package `Pack` (*i.e.* a file `addrule.m` in a folder `+Pack`), you can call it with `Pack.addrule`, while the built-in `addrule` function is simply called by `addrule`.

Best,

Comment: I fully agree. This should always be the preferred way. I would say that it is possible to get the same problem in almost any language of choice. That is why there is classes, namespaces, packages, ... and so on. Further there may be possible that you want to do the same thing for different different "types". Then the same name of the function is preferred, but the code to do it may be completely different.

Answer (score 5):

Get a handle to the original `addrule` function **before** you shadow it with your function:

```
fuzzy_addrule = @addrule;
```

The definition in this statement is "frozen", in the sense that if you later redefine or shadow `addrule` that [won't affect](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html#f4-71621) `fuzzy_addrule`.

You can now define your `addrule` function, which will shadow the original `addrule`, but not `fuzzy_rule`.

```
addrule = @(x,y) x+y; %// very simple example
```

So, to use your function you simply write:

```
>> addrule(3,4)
ans =
     7 %// your function's result
```

To use the original function you call `fuzzy_addrule`:

```
>> fuzzy_addrule(readfis('tipper'),[]) %// example call for fuzzy/addrule function
ans = 
            name: 'tipper'
            type: 'mamdani'
       andMethod: 'min'
        orMethod: 'max'
    defuzzMethod: 'centroid'
       impMethod: 'min'
       aggMethod: 'max'
           input: [1x2 struct]
          output: [1x1 struct]
            rule: [1x3 struct]
```

---

The above requires that the handle to the toolbox function be created before you define your function. If you want to access the toolbox function **after** your function has been defined, you can do it as follows:

1. Temporarily change to the toolbox folder, so that the toolbox function [has precedence](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/function-precedence-order.html) over functions on the path.
2. Define the function handle `fuzzy_addrule`. Since the toolbox function is now visible, the handle refers to that function.
3. Change back to the original folder. Now your function has precedence again (it shadows the toolbox function), but you have the handle `fuzzy_addrule` to the toolbox function.

Code:

```
curdir = pwd; %// take note of current folder
t = which('addrule', '-all'); %// t{1} is your function, t{2} is the toolbox function
fuzdir = regexp(t{2},'.+\\','match'); %// get only folder part
cd(fuzdir{1}); %// change to that folder
fuzzy_addrule = @addrule; %// define function handle
cd(curdir); %// restore folder
```

Once this has been done, each function can be called as described above.

Comment: That's a nice way to bypass the problem. But you have to do that _before_ you  create your personal function (otherwise you have to make it temporarily invisible to matlab). It is also temporary (your next Matlab session will not remember the function handle). But nice trick for a temporary quick solution, +1 for that I might reuse it for myself too.

Comment: @Hoki I completely agree. That's the main drawback of this approach: you need to do it in advance

Comment: Well, if you want to use that over multiple sessions, in a script or function which plan to use both versions, you could always do: `movefile('addrule.m','addrule_backup.m') ; fuzzy_addrule = @addrule ; movefile('addrule_backup.m','addrule.m')`. A bit convoluted but it would do the trick every time.

Comment: @Hoki I found a way to do it _after_ the personal function has been created. Please see edit

Comment: Ha ha .. Well done. I was just reading exactly that on [Matlab central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/97571-how-do-i-specify-an-absolute-pathname-for-a-function-when-using-str2func-to-capture-its-handle) and I was about to suggest you to do something like that. It does work while I couldn't make my solution work. I'll just delete mine.

Comment: Pity that your solution didn't work. Matlab should have a simpler means of calling a function by its full path

Answer (score 0):

Would this be of help:

http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/builtin.html

I am not sure if it works for 'classes' definitions only or if it works in general scripts/functions as well.